# Is checked=no valid in HTML checkboxes?

Tags: html, validation, checkbox

So, I've been fixing up my website. My website of course generates HTML from a "view".

Right now, a portion of my view looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Publish" checked="{=Entry.Publish ? "yes" : "no" =}" value="true" />
```

This is the easiest way to go about this. However, when it generates `checked="no"`, the checkbox will still be checked by default whenever I load the page. Do I really have to exclude the `checked` attribute all together for it to not be checked?

Also, I'm using HTML5 as my doctype.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short version: yes, it needs to be excluded.

The value of the attribute is irrelevant, as long as it is present, the box will be checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Publish" value="true" checked />
```

This is valid in HTML5.

In XHTML, the attribute needed a value and the convention was `checked="checked"` since values like "yes" or "true" implied that the opposites would uncheck the box, which is not true and would confuse beginners.  Similar conventions were adopted for `readonly="readonly"` and `disabled="disabled"`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `checked` is a bool attribute that is "off" when it's absent and "on" when it's present.

W3C reference for [boolean](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute) attributes and for [checked](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-input-element.html#attr-input-checked) attribute.

Answer (score 1):

[from the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html#input.checkbox.attrs.type)

> `checked = "checked"` or `""` (empty string) or empty
>
> Specifies that the element represents a selected control.

Answer (score 0):

You want to include `checked` if it's to be checked, otherwise omit the attribute.